# Using XSLT can I prevent output of consecutive identical values?

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to match only the first occurrence of a value in an XML doc using XSL transforms?

I'd like to print out every value inside f2 but only the first instance of the contents of f1.

XML Data

```
    <doc> 
    <datum>
        <f1>A</f1>
        <f2>Monday</f2>
      </datum>
      <datum>
        <f1>A</f1>
        <f2>Tuesday</f2>
      </datum>
      <datum>
        <f1>B</f1>
        <f2>Wednesday</f2>
    </datum>
    </doc>
```

Output

```
      A
      -Monday
      -Tuesday
      B
      -Wednesday
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I. This is the well-known [Muenchian Grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) for XSLT 1.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kDatumByF1" match="datum" use="f1"/>

 <xsl:template match=
   "datum[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kDatumByF1', f1)[1])]">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;', f1)"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kDatumByF1', f1)/f2" mode="inGroup"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="f2" mode="inGroup">
   - <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<doc>
    <datum>
        <f1>A</f1>
        <f2>Monday</f2>
    </datum>
    <datum>
        <f1>A</f1>
        <f2>Tuesday</f2>
    </datum>
    <datum>
        <f1>B</f1>
        <f2>Wednesday</f2>
    </datum>
</doc>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
A
   - Monday
   - Tuesday
B
   - Wednesday
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution, using [`xsl:for-each-group`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#xsl-for-each-group)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:for-each-group select="datum" group-by="f1">
     <xsl:sequence select="'&#xA;', f1"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/f2"/>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="f2">
   - <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This answer is definitely thoughtful and useful. It may be a bit before I can test it and accept the response (work week).

Comment: What does this statement do? <xsl:sequence select="'&#xA;', f1"/>  Are the control characters intentional?

Comment: This creates (outputs) a sequence of two nodes -- a text node containing the NL (new line) character and a second one that is the `f1` node.

Comment: I was able to use the XSLT 1.0 answer to great success!  Much thanks!  This does not mean that the XSLT 2.0 answer does not work. I just had no way to test it using xsltproc.

Comment: What if there is an <f3> at the same level as <f2> How could i print that as well?  Please let me know if it is proper ettiquite to post a new question.

Comment: @JonnyRo: This is quite simple (just change to the `xsl:apply-templates` and to the last template), but the comments format is inconvenient for exchanging code. I would recommend that you post a new question.

Comment: Novachev http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963390/using-xslt-1-0-and-the-muenchian-grouping-method-how-do-i-prevent-consecutive-ou