# Using XSLT 1.0 and the Muenchian Grouping Method how do I prevent consecutive output of a single field if its value is unchanged

Tags: xml, xslt

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928339/using-xslt-can-i-prevent-output-of-consecutive-identical-values) I asked if it is possible to prevent output of consecutive identical values using XSLT. In this question I extend the input data so that the [Muenchian Grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) for XSLT 1.0 syntax will be clearer.

Is it possible to match only the first occurrence of a value in an XML doc using XSL transforms?

I'd like to print out every value inside f2,f3 but only the first instance of the contents of f1, retaining order.

XML Data

```
    <doc> 
    <datum>
        <f1>One</f1>
        <f2>Monday</f2>
        <f3>January</f3>
      </datum>
      <datum>
        <f1>One</f1>
        <f2>Tuesday</f2>
        <f3>February</f3>
      </datum>
      <datum>
        <f1>Two</f1>
        <f2>Wednesday</f2>
        <f3>March</f3>
    </datum>
    </doc>
```

Output

```
      One
      -Monday-January
      -Tuesday-February
      Two
      -Wednesday-March
```

This is the solution that was proposed for XSLT 1.0 by Dimitre Novatchev for an input data set containing the fields f1 and f2.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kDatumByF1" match="datum" use="f1"/>

 <xsl:template match=
   "datum[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kDatumByF1', f1)[1])]">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;', f1)"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kDatumByF1', f1)/f2" mode="inGroup"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="f2" mode="inGroup">
   - <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works quite well but I am unsure of the syntax to extend to include the field 'f3' in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="text"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
     <xsl:key name="kDatumByF1" match="datum" use="f1"/>

     <xsl:template match=
       "datum[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kDatumByF1', f1)[1])]">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat(f1, '&#xA;')"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup"
           select="key('kDatumByF1', f1)/*[self::f2 or self::f3]" />
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="f2|f3" mode="inGroup">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat('- ',., ' ')"/>
       <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*[self::f2 or self::f3])">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
       </xsl:if>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<doc>
    <datum>
        <f1>One</f1>
        <f2>Monday</f2>
        <f3>January</f3>
    </datum>
    <datum>
        <f1>One</f1>
        <f2>Tuesday</f2>
        <f3>February</f3>
    </datum>
    <datum>
        <f1>Two</f1>
        <f2>Wednesday</f2>
        <f3>March</f3>
    </datum>
</doc>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
One
- Monday - January 
- Tuesday - February 
Two
- Wednesday - March
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

**Do note**:

This solution produces the wanted result even if `f2` and `f3` can come in any order.

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kDatumByF1" match="datum" use="f1"/>

 <xsl:template match=
   "datum[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kDatumByF1', f1)[1])]">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;', f1)"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kDatumByF1', f1)/*[self::f2 | self::f3]" mode="inGroup"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="f2" mode="inGroup">
   - <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="f3" mode="inGroup">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('-',.)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good, but this solution supposes that `f2` always comes before `f3`. What will happen if this assumption doesn't hold?